# Win 7 entered Test mode with black screen, almost nothing worked

Tags: windows-7

​Upon restarting and logging in, my laptop entered test signing mode with a watermark at the corner that says:

> Test Mode
>   Windows 7
>   Build 7601

The desktop was black and I could only move the mouse around. None of the below keyboard shortcuts worked except Win-P which brought up the projector/external monitor switching menu.

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>
>   <kbd>Win</kbd>
>   <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> *
>   <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>
>   <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>

While I was preparing this question (on a different device), Windows exited the test signing mode *(after about 5 minutes I think)* and showed the lock screen *(presumably because I had pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> earlier)*. I unlocked it and the computer was back to being <strike>normal</strike> almost normal, except the watermark is still shown on the desktop above the wallpaper.

I [read that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509241) I have to open *Command Prompt* and issue the following command to disable this test mode:

```
bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

When I checked the current state, indeed the testsigning appears to be turned on:

```
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {8fca152d-a34e-11e2-ab15-606c66041761}
recoveryenabled         Yes
testsigning             Yes                                    <====
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {03ab5fff-8b84-11e2-bdd9-3c970e7a43fb}
nx                      OptIn
```

**Questions:**

- What caused this and what can I do to prevent this in the future?
- Do I still need to run the above command as recommended by Microsoft?
- Will it cause any software to stop working? My most recent installs are *TeamViewer 9.0.25790*, *Unlocker 1.9.2*, and *Adobe AIR 4.0.0.1390*.

Comment: You should first find which unsigned driver forces the boot into Test Mode. See the article [How to verify that system drivers are digitally signed](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/11/how-to-verify-that-system-drivers-are-digitally-signed/). Once you find it, you can sign it yourself : [How to Sign an Unsigned Driver for Windows 7 x64](http://woshub.com/how-to-sign-an-unsigned-driver-for-windows-7-x64/).

Comment: @harrymc An unsigned driver cannot trigger the test mode, which has to be enabled explicitly either by the software installer or the local admin. Also Windows doesn't load self-signed driver unless test mode is enabled. Judging by your response, you have not a good understanding on the matter.

Comment: @guest: Some product might be forcing Test Mode because of some unsigned driver it is using. Finding the driver will find the product. Any problem with that? And if such a product exists and if it must be left as installed, my second link might possibly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509241#MoreInfo) this is used to test applications which are not signed with a digital certificate from Microsoft. This includes the program itself and drivers it uses.

If your computer has come out of test mode it is finished what it is doing and you don't need to worry. It shouldn't affect any of your installed programs.

If you wish to stop this from happening I suggest using a [FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509241) from Microsoft.

Comment: The problem is, this happens on every restart *(just tried again)* and the wait time for "what it is doing" is almost 10 minutes. It's unacceptable! I'm going to issue the command to turn it off, and see if anything breaks.

Comment: I have added a link to Microsoft FixIT if you wish to use this to turn it off.

Comment: The issue appears far worse. Although it does not enter test mode anymore it still shows the unresponsive black screen. I'm gonna have to wait another 10 minutes and go through the cycle of uninstalling recent software to find the culprit... or could it be the offline network drive?

Comment: I can't see how it would be a network drive. If you want to start removing applications don't forget to turn test mode back on. As a side suggestion it might be an idea to run a virus scan on your system.

Comment: Guess what? It **is** the network drive. The drive server went offline today *(still waiting for our IT guy to fix it)* and it looks like Windows is attempting to connect to the drive when I log on - resulting in the black screen and the unresponsive desktop. I *highly suspect* this is due to "Restore previous folder windows at logon" being turned on, and previous failed attempts to connect to the drive left some residual 'ghost windows' that Windows tries to open at log on. If I disconnect the LAN cable, the log on is completely normal and doesn't produce the issue.

Comment: Although I still don't know how all this is related to *test signing mode* `:/`

Comment: Hmm not sure how it got to test mode from there. Would expect Windows to simply not connect to a network...Be interesting to see what happens when they fix the network issue then you can have a poke around some settings to see why Windows reacted this way.

Answer (score 5):

> Given that Test mode was not intentionally enabled, none of the existing answers explain how it got turned on in the first place.

There is insufficient clue as to what triggered the test mode. As such only speculative answer can be given.

From [Microsoft KB2509241](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509241#MoreInfo):

> The test signing mode may start if an installed program is in a test phase because it uses drivers that are not digitally signed by Microsoft.

From [McAfee](https://blogs.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/signed-malware-you-can-runbut-you-cant-hide/):

> Test signing is particularly useful to attackers on 64-bit Windows, on which Microsoft enforces driver signing. By default such drivers will not load. However, Microsoft provides developers with the means of disabling this policy, and malware authors have learned to do the same.

An example of this is the **Banker rootkit**<sup>[[3]](https://securelist.com/blog/incidents/29853/rootkit-banker-now-also-to-64-bit/)[[4]](https://www.virusbulletin.com/uploads/pdf/conference_slides/2011/Kapoor-Mathur-VB2011.pdf)</sup>.

Comment: @guest So malicious software can enable test mode.  Aside from the software development scenario and malicious software, can you think of any other legitimate scenarios that could result in test mode being enabled *without intentional action by the user*? The case I'm investigating doesn't appear to be malicious, yet the user would have not enabled test mode intentionally.

Comment: @Twisty tbh, i dunno. also, you can't fix a bug if you can't reproduce it.

Comment: Test Mode => Unsigned Driver => Any code that is unfavourable for identification:
- software development, save time
- independent developer, save cost
- software piracy, game cheat and malware

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate Matthew's answer and his attempts to help me. However my real issue was different and **rather peculiar**.

Even after turning the *test signing mode* off by issuing the given command, the computer continued to display the black screen and appear non-responsive for about 10 minutes during log on.

**I found out that this is due to:**

- Having a mapped network drive in *Computer* where the drive server had gone down.
- Attempting to connect to the network drive. This leaves some residual *ghost* windows that can't be closed because there are no indications of their existence on screen.
- Having "Restore previous folder windows at logon" enabled in *Folder Options*. This would save the *ghost* windows, and Windows will try to restore them when you next log on.

**To solve the issue:**

- Disconnect the LAN cable while logging on to Windows to avoid the wait.
- In *Folder Options*, disable the option to remember previous folder windows.
- If the above does not help, also try removing the network drive mapping from *Computer*.

**Other than this,** turning the *test signing mode* off did not affect my most recently installed programs. They continued to work normally. However, it looks like the two issues are unrelated.

Comment: @Matthew I have accepted your answer to show my appreciation. However, I am adding this here for anyone else who might have the same issue.